# Sharing dyanmic_reconfigure parameters between nodes

Tags: ros, parameter, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to share dynamic_reconfigure parameters between nodes?

I have two nodes that share a parameter, and it would be nice if I could change it once and have it update both nodes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33016/sharing-dyanmic_reconfigure-parameters-between-nodes/) by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47576 on 2012-04-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to close this out I'm pretty certain that it isn't possible; probably due to the way dynamic_reconfigure uses services.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1